# Is there a more Angular way to get a child element given the elementRef inside a directive

Tags: angular, typescript, dom-events

I have a directive that's responsible for the burger menu on my page and it looks like this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[sideNavToggler]'
})
export class SidenavtogglerDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  private sideNav: HTMLElement
  private burgerButton: HTMLElement

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.sideNav = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.menu__box')
    this.burgerButton = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.menu__btn')
  }

  

  @HostListener('click') toggleOpenClass(){
    if (this.sideNav && this.burgerButton) {
      
      this.sideNav.classList.contains('open')
      ? this.renderer.removeClass(this.sideNav,'open')
      : this.renderer.addClass(this.sideNav, 'open')

      this.burgerButton.classList.contains('active')
      ? this.renderer.removeClass(this.burgerButton,'active')
      : this.renderer.addClass(this.burgerButton,'active')
      
    }
  }
}
```

It works fine but I don't think that using .querySelector is the best practice in Angular applications. I didn't find anything useful on the internet that would be similar to my case. How could I make this code better or is it already sufficient enough? I'm using Angular 16

Comment: For me it helps in this cases to load these logic off to services. Use a service, which then handles the open and close state. And update an observable (or whatever works best for you) to handle the state. Maybe add an ID to your side-Navs if you have multiple of them and pass this ID to the service.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ContentChild` when you are using directive, please find below a working example for you to reference.

css

```
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
.open {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.hamburger-menu {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

main.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { SidenavtogglerDirective } from './side-nav-toggler.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [SidenavtogglerDirective],
  template: `
    <div class="hamburger-menu" sideNavToggler>
      click inside to change color<br/>
    <label class="menu__btn active" for="menu__toggle" #menuButton>
      <span>label</span>
    </label>

    <ul class="menu__box open" #menuBox>
      <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">hello</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

directive

```
import {
  Directive,
  HostListener,
  Renderer2,
  AfterViewInit,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef,
  ContentChild,
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[sideNavToggler]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class SidenavtogglerDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @ContentChild('menuBox') menuBox!: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
  @ContentChild('menuButton') menuButton!: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {}

  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
  toggleOpenClass() {
    if (this.menuBox && this.menuButton) {
      console.log(this.menuBox.nativeElement.classList.contains('open'));
      this.menuBox.nativeElement.classList.contains('open')
        ? this.renderer.removeClass(this.menuBox.nativeElement, 'open')
        : this.renderer.addClass(this.menuBox.nativeElement, 'open');

      this.menuButton.nativeElement.classList.contains('active')
        ? this.renderer.removeClass(this.menuButton.nativeElement, 'active')
        : this.renderer.addClass(this.menuButton.nativeElement, 'active');
    }
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-6ylzgw?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fside-nav-toggler.directive.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css&title=Angular%20Starter)